# UDP multi-client server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

Problem is to make UDP server send data to an array of clients, that already make a connection to a server. All clients IPs are stored on the server side linkedlist, but for some reason, i am able to send response only, and only to the last made connection from the client.

So basic description of what I want to achieve is:

1. few clients made a connection and i can see their messages
2. every client's IP is stored in linkedlist
3. if there is more than 1 client stored in linkedlist, program will go through every IP in its storage, and if IP of current client is DIFFERENT from what is stored in linkedlist -> server is sending to this IP last message from current client
4. on the server side, if message was typed, program will go through every IP stored in LinkedList and send this message to every client

server.c

```
#include "server.h"
#include "linkedList.h"

volatile sig_atomic_t dones = 0;

void server(){
    pthread_t r, s;
    int server_d;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    struct params args;

    linkedList** iter = getIteratorList();

    if((server_d = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("\nsocket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(server.sin_zero, 8);

    args.client = &client;
    args.server_d = &server_d;
    args.iter = iter;

    if(bind(server_d, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
        perror("\nbind");
        exit(-1);
    }

    pthread_create(&r, NULL, receives, (void*)&args);
    pthread_create(&s, NULL, sends, (void*)&args);
    pthread_join(s, NULL);

}

void* receives(void* data){

    int flag = 0;
    struct params* args = data;
    int* server_d = args->server_d;
    struct sockaddr_in* client = args->client;
    linkedList** iter = args->iter;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];
    struct sockaddr_in tmp;


    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = terms;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);

    while(!dones){

        if(flag == 0){
            if(recvfrom(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, &length) > 0){
                flag = 1;
                decrypt(buffer);
                printf("[%s]:%s", inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr), buffer);


                //some new staff





                if(checkList(inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr)) != 1){
                    addList(*client);
                    printf("[DEBUG]clients IP is stored. size of LL: %d\n", sizeList());
                }
                if(sizeList() > 1){
                    beginList();
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
                        printf("[DEBUG]Stored IP[%d]: %s\n", i, (*iter)->address);
                        nextList();
                        }
                }
                    beginList();
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
                        if (strcmp((*iter)->address, inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr)) != 0){

                            printf("[DEBUG]there is a client to send a message to. message: %s", buffer);

                            printf("[DEBUG]resend: %s --> %s\n",inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr), (*iter)->address);

                            tmp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((*iter)->address);
                            tmp.sin_family = client->sin_family;
                            tmp.sin_port = client->sin_port;
                            bzero(tmp.sin_zero, 8);

                            printf("[DEBUG]IP in tmp.sin_addr: %s\n", inet_ntoa(tmp.sin_addr));
                            printf("[DEBUG]IP in client->sin_addr: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr));

                            printf("[DEBUG]message send: %d\n", (int)sendto(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&tmp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)));
                            nextList();
                        }else{
                            nextList();
                        }
                    }










                // end of new staff

            }
            bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        }else{
            if(recvfrom(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, &length) == 0){
                flag = 0;
            }else{
                decrypt(buffer);
                printf("[%s]:%s", inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr), buffer);





                //some new staff












                if(checkList(inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr)) != 1){
                    addList(*client);
                    printf("[DEBUG]clients IP is stored. size of LL: %d\n", sizeList());
                }
                if(sizeList() > 1){
                    beginList();
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
                        printf("[DEBUG]Stored IP[%d]: %s\n", i, (*iter)->address);
                        nextList();
                        }
                }
                    beginList();
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
                        if (strcmp((*iter)->address, inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr)) != 0){

                            printf("[DEBUG]there is a client to send a message to. message: %s", buffer);

                            printf("[DEBUG]resend: %s --> %s\n",inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr), (*iter)->address);

                            tmp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((*iter)->address);
                            tmp.sin_family = client->sin_family;
                            tmp.sin_port = client->sin_port;
                            bzero(tmp.sin_zero, 8);

                            printf("[DEBUG]IP in tmp.sin_addr: %s\n", inet_ntoa(tmp.sin_addr));
                            printf("[DEBUG]IP in client->sin_addr: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr));

                            printf("[DEBUG]message send: %d\n", (int)sendto(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&tmp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)));
                            nextList();
                        }else{
                            nextList();
                        }
                    }










                // end of new staff

            }
            bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        }

    }

    printf("Server terminated.\n");

    return NULL;
}

void* sends(void* data){

    struct params* args = data;
    int* server_d = args->server_d;
    struct sockaddr_in* client = args->client;
    linkedList** iter = args->iter;
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];
    struct sockaddr_in tmp;

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = terms;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    while(!dones){

        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, stdin);

        encrypt(buffer);
/*
        if(sendto(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1){
            printf("Message was not sent...\n");
        }
*/


        tmp.sin_addr.s_addr = client->sin_addr.s_addr;
        tmp.sin_family = client->sin_family;
        tmp.sin_port = client->sin_port;
        bzero(tmp.sin_zero, 8);

        beginList();
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
            tmp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((*iter)->address);
            printf("[DEBUG]sending to address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(tmp.sin_addr));
            sendto(*server_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&tmp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            nextList();
        }

    }

    printf("Server terminated.\n");

    return NULL;
}

void terms(int signum){

    dones = 1;
    if(clearList() == 0) printf("\n\nLinkedList was succesfully deleted.\n");
    printf("\nTerminating server...\n");

}
```

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "const.h"
#include "encrypt.h"
#include "linkedList.h"

struct params{
    struct sockaddr_in* client;
    int* server_d;
    linkedList** iter;
};

volatile sig_atomic_t dones;

void server();
void* receives(void*);
void* sends(void*);
void terms(int);

#endif
```

linkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_
#define LINKED_LIST_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ll{

    int socket;
    char* address;
    struct ll* next;
    struct ll* prev;

} linkedList;


linkedList* initList(struct sockaddr_in);
linkedList* addList(struct sockaddr_in);
linkedList* removeList(char*);
unsigned short int clearList();
unsigned short int sizeList();
linkedList* nextList();
linkedList* prevList();
linkedList* beginList();
linkedList* endList();
linkedList** getIteratorList();
unsigned short int checkList(char*);


#endif
```

linkedList.c

```
#include "linkedList.h"

static linkedList* iterator = NULL;

linkedList* initList(struct sockaddr_in p_new){

    iterator = (linkedList*) malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    if(iterator == NULL) return NULL;
    iterator->next = NULL;
    iterator->prev = NULL;
    iterator->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
    strcpy(iterator->address, inet_ntoa(p_new.sin_addr));
    return iterator;

}
linkedList* addList(struct sockaddr_in p_new){

    if(iterator == NULL){

        return initList(p_new);

    }
    endList();
    iterator->next = (linkedList*) malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    if(iterator->next == NULL) return NULL;
    iterator->next->next = NULL;
    iterator->next->prev = iterator;
    iterator->next->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
    strcpy(iterator->next->address, inet_ntoa(p_new.sin_addr));
    return iterator = iterator->next;

}
linkedList* removeList(char* p_address){

    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        if(strcmp(iterator->address, p_address) == 0){

            if(iterator->prev == NULL){

                iterator = iterator->next;
                free(iterator->prev->address);
                free(iterator->prev);
                iterator->prev = NULL;
                return iterator;

            }else if(iterator->next == NULL){

                iterator = iterator->prev;
                free(iterator->next->address);
                free(iterator->next);
                iterator->next = NULL;
                return iterator;

            }else{

                linkedList* tmp = iterator->next;
                iterator->prev->next = iterator->next;
                iterator->next->prev = iterator->prev;
                free(iterator->address);
                free(iterator);
                return iterator = tmp;

            }


        }else{
            nextList();
        }
    }
    beginList();
    return iterator;
}
unsigned short int clearList(){

    if (iterator == NULL) return 404;

    endList();

    while( (iterator->next != NULL && iterator->prev != NULL) ){

        iterator = iterator->prev;
        free(iterator->next->address);
        free(iterator->next);
        iterator->next = NULL;

    }

    free(iterator);
    iterator = NULL;
    return 0;

}
unsigned short int sizeList(){

    unsigned short int size = 0;
    unsigned int tmp_range = 0;
    if(iterator == NULL) return size;
    while(iterator->prev != NULL){
        tmp_range++;
        prevList();
    }

    while(iterator->next != NULL){
        size++;
        nextList();
    }
    size++;
    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp_range; i++){
        nextList();
    }
    return size;

}
linkedList* nextList(){

    if (iterator == NULL) return NULL;

    if(iterator->next == NULL) return iterator; else return iterator = iterator->next;

}
linkedList* prevList(){

    if (iterator == NULL) return NULL;

    if(iterator->prev == NULL) return iterator; else return iterator = iterator->prev;

}
linkedList* beginList(){

    if (iterator == NULL) return NULL;

    while(iterator->prev != NULL){
        prevList();
    }

    return iterator;

}
linkedList* endList(){

    if (iterator == NULL) return NULL;

    while(iterator->next != NULL){
        nextList();
    }

    return iterator;

}
linkedList** getIteratorList(){
    return &iterator;
}
unsigned short int checkList(char* p_str){

    if(iterator == NULL) return 0;

    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        if(strcmp(iterator->address, p_str) == 0){

            return 1;

        }else nextList();
    }
    beginList();
    return 0;
}
```

client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "const.h"
#include "encrypt.h"

struct paramc{
    struct sockaddr_in* server;
    int* client_d;
};

volatile sig_atomic_t donec;

void client(char*);
void* receivec(void*);
void* sendc(void*);
void termc(int);

#endif
```

client.c

```
#include "client.h"

volatile sig_atomic_t donec = 0;

void client(char* address){

    pthread_t r, s;
    int client_d;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct paramc args;

    if((client_d = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("\nsocket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    bzero(server.sin_zero, 8);


    args.server = &server;
    args.client_d = &client_d;

    pthread_create(&r, NULL, receivec, (void*)&args);
    pthread_create(&s, NULL, sendc, (void*)&args);
    pthread_join(s, NULL);

}

void* receivec(void* data){

    struct paramc* args = data;
    struct sockaddr_in* server = args->server;
    int* client_d = args->client_d;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = termc;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    while(!donec){

        if(recvfrom(*client_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)server, &length) > 0){
            decrypt(buffer);
            printf("[%s]:%s", inet_ntoa(server->sin_addr), buffer);
            bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        }

    }

    printf("Client terminated.\n");

    return NULL;
}

void* sendc(void* data){

    struct paramc* args = data;
    struct sockaddr_in* server = args->server;
    int* client_d = args->client_d;
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = termc;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    while(!donec){

        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_MAX);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, stdin);

        encrypt(buffer);

        sendto(*client_d, buffer, BUFFER_MAX - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    }

    printf("Client terminated.\n");

    return NULL;
}

void termc(int signum){

    donec = 1;
    printf("\nTerminating client...\n");

}
```

const.h

```
#ifndef CONST_H_
#define CONST_H_

#define PORT 15151
#define BUFFER_MAX 1024

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"

//#define linkedlist_test
#ifdef linkedlist_test
#include "linkedList.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


#ifndef linkedlist_test
    system("clear");

    if(argc < 2){

        server();

    }else{

        client(argv[1]);

    }
#endif
#ifdef linkedlist_test
    struct sockaddr_in test1;
    test1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test1.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    test1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.101");
    bzero(test1.sin_zero, 8);

    struct sockaddr_in test2;
    test2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test2.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    test2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.102");
    bzero(test2.sin_zero, 8);

    struct sockaddr_in test3;
    test3.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test3.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    test3.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.103");
    bzero(test3.sin_zero, 8);

    struct sockaddr_in test4;
    test4.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test4.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    test4.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.104");
    bzero(test4.sin_zero, 8);

    struct sockaddr_in test5;
    test5.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test5.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    test5.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.105");
    bzero(test5.sin_zero, 8);

    linkedList** iterator = getIteratorList();
    printf("address: %p/%p\torder: %d\n", *iterator, addList(test1), sizeList());
    printf("address: %p/%p\torder: %d\n", *iterator, addList(test2), sizeList());
    printf("address: %p/%p\torder: %d\n", *iterator, addList(test3), sizeList());
    printf("address: %p/%p\torder: %d\n", *iterator, addList(test4), sizeList());
    printf("address: %p/%p\torder: %d\n", *iterator, addList(test5), sizeList());

    printf("vypis testovych struktur priamo:\n%s\n", inet_ntoa(test1.sin_addr));
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(test2.sin_addr));
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(test3.sin_addr));
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(test4.sin_addr));
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(test5.sin_addr));

    printf("========================\n");
    checkList("192.168.1.104");
    printf("checkList() test: adresa -//-.104 sa nachadza: %p, plna adresa je %s\n", (*iterator), (*iterator)->address);

    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        printf("[%p]list\'s output [%d]: %s\n", *iterator, i, (*iterator)->address);
        nextList();
    }
    printf("========================\n");

    removeList("192.168.1.102");
    printf("deleting 192.168.1.102\n");
    printf("size: %d\n", sizeList());


    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        printf("[%p]list\'s output [%d]: %s\n", *iterator, i, (*iterator)->address);
        nextList();
    }
    printf("========================\n");
    removeList("192.168.1.101");
    printf("deleting 192.168.1.101\n");
    printf("size: %d\n", sizeList());

    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        printf("[%p]list\'s output [%d]: %s\n", *iterator, i, (*iterator)->address);
        nextList();
    }

    printf("========================\n");
    removeList("192.168.1.105");
    printf("deleting 192.168.1.105\n");
    printf("size: %d\n", sizeList());



    beginList();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeList(); i++){
        printf("[%p]list\'s output [%d]: %s\n", *iterator, i, (*iterator)->address);
        nextList();
    }
    printf("========================\n");

    printf("removing the whole list\n");
    if(clearList() == 0) printf("successfully removed\n"); else printf("some chiki-briki is not right. FAILUREEE!");
    printf("size: %d\n", sizeList());
    printf("========================\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

encrypt.c and encrypt.h are just two functions char* encrypt(char*) and char* decrypt(char*) that did nothing with a string --> WIP

Comment: 'and only to the last made connection from the client' and 'linked-list'.  Why does that sound so familiar?   There are a LOT of linked-list posts on SO that fall foul of copying pointers into a list instead of the data pointed to.  That results in all the LL nodes having pointers that address the last data entered.....

Comment: there are several functions that are not to be used inside a signal handler.  `printf()` is one of those functions.  in general, a signal handler should just set a flag and the main processing (in this case, the threads) should be checking that flag.

Comment: the posted code is missing the prototypes and implementations/bodies of the functions: `addList()` `beginList()` `nextList()` and `clearList()`  however the source of the problem is (most likely) in one (or more) of those functions.  Please post a [mcve] otherwise, this question is offtopic for stackoverflow and we cannot guess as to the contents of those functions.

Comment: You are updating your linked list from two threads and a signal handler without any attempt at concurrency protection. NB There is no such thing as a UDP connection.

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for pointing out problem with signal handler. Next i added my other libraries, there is some testing of LinkedList in main.c, just uncomment the #define linkedlist_test (i was pretty sure about LL, but proud one is very likely to be a looser)

Comment: @EJP I choose my words poorly

Comment: You misuse standard terminology. If electrical engineers did that we would all be dead.

Comment: @EJP I choose my words poorly about UDP connection, You are right. About my unconditional threading of linked list, i updating it in one thread only, the other one is just reading from it, BUT i see where the problem could be in a future (i work with iterator in LL, so if there going to be such a situation, where server is going to send message and LL is going to be used in other thread, it will end up badly), thank you

Comment: If you update it in one thread the reading threads will encounter failures. You need some form of mutual exclusion.

Comment: "*Problem is to make UDP server send data to an array of clients, that already make a connection to a server.*" - why not use multicasting instead? That way, your server can send data to only 1 fixed IP/Port for a multicast group, and any client that is interested in the data can subscribe to that group.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is also true, and actually it will eliminate complication with sending data to each client from server (message from server to each client). thanks for the advise!

Comment: Just few minutes ago, i tried to look into ports, and maybe i found an error. When I make a structure of sockaddr_in, there is a port segment, but this port is just a DESTINATION port, so I think i will try to bind clients to listen on my defined port 15151. Basically port is given by system consideration on host (through which data are sended). Does it make any sense?

Comment: When calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.. 2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: @yanouski - Did you run multiple clients on the same host?